# Explicit lifetime for Vec to slice conversation

Tags: rust

I want a callback on changes inside a list, so I created simple example:

```
struct Foo;

struct FooList {
    list: Vec<Foo>,
    on_change_cb: Vec<Box<FnMut(& mut [Foo])>>,
}

impl FooList {
 /*
    pub fn register_on_change_cb2<F>(&mut self, cb: F) where F: FnMut(&mut [Foo]) {
        self.on_change_cb.push(Box::new(cb));
    }*/

    pub fn register_on_change_cb(&mut self, cb: Box<FnMut(&mut [Foo])>) {
        self.on_change_cb.push(cb);
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, foo: Foo) {
        self.list.push(foo);
        self.on_change();
    }


    fn on_change(&mut self) {
        for cb in &mut self.on_change_cb {
            cb(&mut self.list);
        }
    }
}
```

1. I don't give any explicit hint to the compiler about lifetimes here: `Vec<Box<FnMut(& mut [Foo])>>`, so what lifetimes will the compiler use here? If I change the code like this:

   ```
   struct FooList<'a> {
       list: Vec<Foo>,
       on_change_cb: Vec<Box<FnMut(&'a mut [Foo])>>,
   }
   impl<'a> FooList<'a> {
   ```

   I get a compile time error:

   > error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow 
   >   expression due to conflicting requirements
2. How can I explicitly set the lifetimes in some way such that the lifetime of `& mut [Foo]` for the callback is less than, but not equal to the lifetime of the whole `FooList` object?
3. I have commented `register_on_change_cb2`, I want to allow calling `register_on_change_cb` without usage of `Box::new` but failed. If you uncomment `register_on_change_cb2`, you get the error:

   > error[E0310]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough

   How can I fix this error without the requirement of a `'static` lifetime for callback? I just want to call `Box::new` on my side.

Comment: Please have only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: @Shepmaster Actually, I think that these questions is different side of the same thing, how `Vec` + slice + `FnMut` cooperate, that's why I combine these questions into one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer your questions 1 and 3, because question 2 is either redundant or orthogonal to the others, and I can't tell what you really want to achieve by it. Perhaps it deserves a question of its own.

1. If you have a function that takes a reference, but it doesn't need any lifetime information about the reference, it must be able to accept a reference of **any** lifetime. Here's the explicit syntax for that (this is what the compiler infers from the code you wrote):

   ```
   on_change_cb: Vec<Box<for<'b> FnMut(&'b mut [Foo])>>,
   ```

   This is called a [higher ranked trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) or HRTB for short. They're mostly useful for the `Fn` traits, which is why they exist.

3. If the type of `on_change_cb` is `Vec<Box<FnMut(&mut [Foo])>>`, which doesn't carry any lifetime information, then it must not contain any references (except `'static` references). You need to say that the type implementing `FnMut` may also contain (non-`'static`) references, as long as they outlive some lifetime `'a`:

   ```
   struct FooList<'a> {
       list: Vec<Foo>,
       on_change_cb: Vec<Box<FnMut(&mut [Foo]) + 'a>>,
   }
   ```

   This reads something like: "For each `FooList` object, there is a lifetime `'a` such that every callback in the `FooList` contains only references that live for at least `'a`." This interpretation may make it easier to write the prototype for `register_on_change_cb2`: it takes a callback that *also* contains only references that live for at least `'a`.

   ```
   impl<'a> FooList<'a> {
       pub fn register_on_change_cb2<F>(&mut self, cb: F)
           where F: FnMut(&mut [Foo]) + 'a
       {
           self.on_change_cb.push(Box::new(cb));
       }
   ```

   (I *think* I have the [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) of `'a` correct now -- a previous version of this answer had it wrong.)

   The `'a` lifetime lets the compiler guarantee that you never put a callback in the `Box` (and therefore the `Vec`) unless it lasts at least as long as the `FooList` itself. This is important because closures can capture references to values in the enclosing scope, as in the following code ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8303a58633f1a494413ad918cf14aad7&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

   ```
   let longlived = String::from("hello");
   let mut list = FooList {
       list: Vec::new(),
       on_change_cb: Vec::new(),
   };
   list.register_on_change_cb2(|_| println!("{}", longlived)); // ok

   let shortlived = String::from("hello");
   list.register_on_change_cb2(|_| println!("{}", shortlived)); // `shortlived` does not live long enough

   list.push(Foo);
   ```

   In this example, you can't insert the closure that captures `shortlived` because it doesn't outlive the (inferred) lifetime `'a`. But you *can* insert the closure that captures `longlived`, because the compiler can infer a lifetime `'a` that satisfies both constraints:

   - `'a` must outlive `list`, because `list` is of type `FooList<'a>`.
   - `longlived` must outlive `'a`, because `|_| println!("{}", longlived)`, which borrows `longlived`, is bounded by `'a` in the call to `register_on_change_cb2`.

   If you want to say that the callbacks don't borrow *anything* by-reference, the `'a` lifetime is unnecessary, and in that case you could just add the `'static` bound that [the compiler suggests](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d74ffde530c2cf55c5a373ce8b4967e3&version=stable&backtrace=0):

   ```
       pub fn register_on_change_cb2<F>(&mut self, cb: F)
           where F: FnMut(&mut [Foo]) + 'static
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but why lifetime matter in `3`? I put `cb` into `Box` and I get it by value?

Comment: @user1244932 `Box`ing something doesn't erase knowledge of the references it contains. I added an example that illustrates how the `'a` lifetime ensures that `cb` contains only references that outlive the `FooList`.